# accessing data using datatool when headers aren't available

Tags: datatool

I have a series of `csv` files I'm expecting to receive on a regular basis, and there are two problems with these files.

1. I am not guaranteed to have headers.
2. I cannot rely on how many data entries there will be per row (sometimes there may be 50 or so, sometimes more)

What I am guaranteed is that, let's say, the 1st, 10th, and 30th column have the data I want.  Up until now I've been using a perl script to *collapse* these `csv` files to something where the rows have only the elements I'm interested in.

Is there a way in `datatool` to tell it to create headers for certain columns and ignore the rest?

For example, it would be nice to be able to do something like the following:

```
\DTLloaddb[noheader,headers={modelname=1,serialnumber=10,weight=30}]{itemweights}{somefile.csv}
```

which would mean that `modelname` is in the first column, `serialnumber` is in the 10th column and `weight` is in column 30.

Here is an extremely simplified example of a `csv` file I might work with.

```
  "toaster",    "",      "",       "",       "234-02015-23-948",  "",  "",      "",      "",      "",  "1255",  "",  "" 
  "blender",    "junk",  "",       "",       "753-20842-46-824",  "",  "",      "junk",  "",      "",  "1567",  "" 
  "microwave",  "",      "",       "stuff",  "376-73178-68-487",  "",  "",      "",      "junk",  "",  "2434",  "",  "",  ""
  "radio",      "",      "stuff",  "junk",   "724-86499-61-446",  "",  "",      "",      "junk",  "",  "2343" 
  "tv",         "",      "",       "",       "423-90219-60-149",  "",  "junk",  "",      "",      "",  "3023",  "",  "",  ""
```

A solution that creates a header for every column is completely infeasible because I have upwards of 50 columns only 3 or 4 of which I'm interested in.

What I'd like to be able to do is write:

```
\DTLloaddb[noheader,headers={appliance=1,serialnumber=5,detailnumber=11}]{itemweights}{somefile.csv}
```

Comment: When you say "not guaranteed to have headers" does that mean sometimes you do and sometimes you don't?  If so, I assume you can tell by inspection if the first row is or isn't a header?

Comment: If `datatool` doesn't turn out to be feasible `pgfplotstable` can be an alternative which can handle this.

Comment: @alanmunn.  Sometimes there are are headers, but only certain columns have them and many columns have duplicate names suchs *comment*, but most columns lack a header even when others have them.

Comment: So that means there is always a header *row*, even if every column doesn't make use of it.  This is an important distinction. :)

Comment: @alanmunn. But `datatool` in such examples, if I tell `datatool` there is a header, it complains about duplicate header names.

Comment: Yes, I understand, so what you need to do is treat it as `noheader` and then deal with the first row manually, plus ignore columns.

Comment: @alanmunn.  I can distinguish myself when there is and is not a header.  I've been using *perl* to do that.  What I would like to be able to do it skip *perl*.  To clarify, occasionally, the data file completely lacks headers.  When the data file does include headers, they are only even partially there and not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @percusse.  Thank you for suggesting `pgfplotstable`.  I hadn't known about it.  I'm a bit reticent to use it because I continually find the various documentation for `pgf` stuff frustrating: I find I often have to read huge sections of the documentation to get the information I need.  My job doesn't allow me the luxury of reading a manual cover to cover to learn some *very cool* tricks.  I like what the `pgf` stuff can do, but the cost (cost of time) to do something simple is often immense.

Comment: @alanmunn, per your last comment, which I missed while writing mine, that's exactly what I want to do.  But, I thought that's also what I was trying to illustrate in the question when I put `noheader` in the `\DTLloaddb`.

Comment: @A.Ellett Indeed it requires some affinity to key value system. Please take my suggestion as a backup if this turns out to be infeasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, this isn't too difficult to do, although perhaps not in exactly the way you envision.  When `datatool` reads in a file, and you don't specify the headers, it will automatically assign headers of `Column1` ... `Column-n` to your database. If you specify `noheader` then you don't need to worry about duplicate column names. You can use this to pick columns selectively from the database when you iterate through.  In the example below, I'm assuming the file has a header row but it contains duplicates or blanks in some columns.  If the file sometimes truly has no header, then the example would need to be modified to deal with that case as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
1,,,Duplicate,5,Duplicate,7,8,9,10
Cell-1-2,Cell-2-2,Cell-3-2,Cell-4-2,Cell-5-2,Cell-6-2,Cell-7-2,Cell-8-2,Cell-9-2,Cell-10-2
Cell-1-3,Cell-2-3,Cell-3-3,Cell-4-3,Cell-5-3,Cell-6-3,Cell-7-3,Cell-8-3,Cell-9-3,Cell-10-3
Cell-1-4,Cell-2-4,Cell-3-4,Cell-4-4,Cell-5-4,Cell-6-4,Cell-7-4,Cell-8-4,Cell-9-4,Cell-10-4
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{testdb}{\jobname.csv}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
ONE & SIX & NINE
\DTLforeach{testdb}{\one=Column1,\six=Column6,\nine=Column9}{%
\DTLiffirstrow{\\}{%
\one & \six & \nine\\
}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I can't find this approach in the manual.  How did you know to do this?

Comment: Section 5.2   (p. 39 or thereabouts, depending on your version) of the manual discusses this in the description of the "keys" option

Comment: Ah ha!  I'd seen that but I hadn't understood how to use it.  Thanks all over again!